# Cardinality of all cardinal numbers less than a given cardinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

For a given cardinal number $\aleph_{\alpha}$ we define
$$X_{\alpha}= \{\aleph_{\beta}; \aleph_{\beta}<\aleph_{\alpha}\}.$$
We can easily prove that

1) $card(X_{\alpha}) \leq \aleph_{\alpha}^{+}=2^{\aleph_{\alpha}},$ and

2) if $\alpha$ is a successor cardinal number, then  $card(X_{\alpha}) \leq \aleph_{\alpha}.$

Now, can we show that $card(X_{\alpha}) \leq \aleph_{\alpha}$ in general?
What we can say about the cardinality of $X_{\alpha?}$

Comment: $|X_\alpha|=|\alpha|$ surely?

Comment: Is there any reason?

Comment: There exists a natural bijection $\alpha \rightarrow X_{\alpha}$, which is $\beta \longmapsto \aleph_{\beta}$.

Comment: at most X_alpha.