# cardinality of all cardinal numbers less than a cardinal number

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

For a cardinal number $\alpha$ what is the cardinality of the set

$X=\{\beta, \beta$ is a cardinal number with $\beta<\alpha\}?$

Can we say for example that $card(X)=\alpha$ or $card(X)\leq \alpha?$

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111102/cardinality-of-all-cardinal-numbers-less-than-a-given-cardinal

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is obvious, because $X\subset \alpha$. The equality, however, is false : for instance if $\alpha=\omega_1$, then $X= \omega+1$, so $Card(X) = \omega$.

I don't think there is a general formula for this; the thing is that if $\kappa$ is a cardinal with $\kappa = \aleph_\alpha$, then $X= \omega\cup\{\aleph_\beta, \beta <\alpha\}$, so that $Card(X) = \aleph_0 + Card(\alpha)$. But $\alpha$ can be $<\kappa$, and it can be $=\kappa$, so there isn't much more you can say

Comment: If  $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal you can say $| X | \geq \text{ cf}(X)$.

Comment: @RobertShore : sure you can say plenty of stuff; what I meant is there's no magic formula or something. By the way, your inequality is an immediate consequence of what I said about $\aleph_\alpha$ (you probably meant $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$, otherwise it's essentially trivial and it's the case for any well-ordered set)

Comment: You're right, I did mean cf($\kappa$).